# how to create auto email send after x days

Tags: magento-1.9, forms

I have install extension for a testimonial.
now I want to send email to customer after 7 days of purchase to let them write their review on the testimonial page

how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send an email on every 7 days you can use [CRON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job feature. I am assuming that you know how to create a module so to set CRON job for every 7 days you need to write `crontab` in your module `config.xml`

```
<crontab>
        <jobs>
            <testimonial_review_send>
                <schedule><cron_expr>0 0 * * 0</cron_expr></schedule>
                <run><model>mymodulename/observer::sendTestimonialEmail</model></run>
            </testimonial_review_send>
        </jobs>
</crontab>
```

It will execute every 7 days on 00:00 time. If you want to customize then you can just customize `CRON` job expression. Here `CRON` expression is `0 0 * * 0` and the explanation of `CRON` expression is (source: wikipedia ),

[image]

Now you need to create an `observer.php` file(in `model` directory) with `sendTestimonialEmail` method.

```
class Training_Testimonial_Model_Observer
{

   public function sendTestimonialEmail()
    {
    // perform your magic here
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to create a module :(

Comment: You can find lots of article about this on Intenet like http://inchoo.net/magento/programming-magento/magento-hello-world-module-extension/ @muzramn